# Different spacing between title, subtitle and text, and subsection text alignment

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

1. Is there any way to make first line of subsection title be aligned with \parident and second line -- aligned to the left?

[image]

2. I need to make different spacing between title, subtitle and subsubtitle:
   a. Spacing between section title and subsection title -- 8mm;
   b. Spacing between any title and text -- 15mm;
   c. Spacing between text and subsection title --- 1,5 linespacing.

Tried to do this way, but it doesn't give right results:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}



\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{16}{15}\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{} 

\titlespacing{\section}{}{10mm}{10mm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{25mm}{15mm} 
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{\parindent}{25mm}{15mm} 

\begin{document}

\section{For three years, car mechanic Paen Long stayed up long after his wife went to bed each night, spending countless hours watching videos on YouTube}

\subsection{For three years, car mechanic Paen Long stayed up long after his wife went to bed each night, spending countless hours watching videos on YouTube}

\subsubsection{For three years, car mechanic Paen Long stayed up long after his wife went to bed each night, spending countless hours watching videos on YouTube}

For three years, car mechanic Paen Long stayed up long after his wife went to bed each night, spending countless hours watching videos on YouTube.

\end{document}
```

UPD. After system upgrade (including texlive upgrade) there is no text in titles if I use \titleformat.

Comment: `\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15‌​}\bfseries}{\thesubs‌​ection}{1em}{}` does the job for the first point. For the second (which is not very clear, I confess) try to with the option `[largestsep]`/`[aftersep]` (the latter is the default).

Comment: @Moriambar: Done, mylord.

Comment: Is the cyrillic script relevant to the question? If not, please replace it with some text using the latin alphabet. More people will have a look and the answer will help more people as well.

Comment: @Bernard, solutions works with 1st point!

Comment: @Johannes_B, I've edited post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of spacing between section and subsection can't have an automatic solution,  insofar as you can't know in advance whether the section title is followed by some text, or a subsection title. So I think  you'll have to do it by hand.

The following code is a solution to what I've understood of your requirements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%,T2A
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%,russian
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}

\usepackage[aftersep]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{16}{15}\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10mm}{10mm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{25mm}{15mm}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{25mm}{0.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\section{For three years, car mechanic Paen Long stayed up long after his wife went to bed each night, spending countless hours watching videos on YouTube}\vspace{-4ex}

\subsection{For three years, car mechanic Paen Long stayed up long after his wife went to bed each night, spending countless hours watching videos on YouTube}

\subsubsection{For three years, car mechanic Paen Long stayed up long after his wife went to bed each night, spending countless hours watching videos on YouTube}

For three years, car mechanic Paen Long stayed up long after his wife went to bed each night, spending countless hours watching videos on YouTube.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx! It works for me, but only in MWE. In my document where knitr is used \vspace does nothing.

Comment: I don't know `knitr`, so I can't help unfortunately. Just in case, try `\vspace*` or `\leavevmode\vspace`.

Comment: Sorry, everything works clear, it was just my stupid mistake. Big thanks again!